# I have php5 installed on my ubuntu system but I'm struggling to find a way to run it

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Very new to Linux but I have a good idea of the terminal and all that stuff and how it works. So I have php5 and apache2 installed via the terminal and the code editor I use is sublime text. I can't find a way online to run my own php scripts from sublime text on my localhost in the browser. I understand they have to be in the var/www/ folder and I've tried to create a file hello.php in the folder via the terminal but when I try to save it it brings me to my documents folder and I cant save it in my var/www/ folder.

Comment: Or is it possible to copy my php file from where it's saved to the var/www/ folder and do it that way?

Answer (score 0):

First to check if PHP has successfully installed on your Linux server.

Step 1 :-
Type it in the console

```
php -v
```

If there's a value like mine :

> PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21 (cli) (built: Feb  9 2017 20:54:58)
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies

It means you've successfully installed the php.

Step 2 :-

Head to 
`/var/www/` or `/var/www/html`

Create a php script with the following function:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

and save it as index.php.

Then head over your browser and type the address:

```
http://youripaddress/index.php
```